# How to display only the data requested by user on the homepage using flutter and google firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to find a way to design a part of my program that shows a bunch of restaurants. The problem is that I want my client to be able to search which areas he wants his restaurant to be in, and or how many stars should the restaurant have. Now, in my firestore I have a collection called restaurants, and I have the areas as the documents of the collection, and then I have the restaurants' ratings as the subcollections of each document, and finally, I have the name, phone numbers and the full address as the documents of each subcollection. I have no clue how to tell my program to show only the restaurants that are in certain areas or have a certain amount of stars.

For example, let's say I only want my restaurants to be in Los Angles, and Compton and they should have either 2, or 3 stars.

How can I store the information on firestore and how should I retrieve it in order for my program to only display restaurants with the desired information.

I've searched all over the internet and been stuck on this problem for 2 days so any help would be absolutely appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you can find all of your questions in official firestore beginners tutorial on official Google Firebase: [Part 1](https://youtu.be/v_hR4K4auoQ). There are 6 parts of this tutorial and i think they have exactly the same example with restaurants.

Comment: Filtering by a number of stars is as straightforward as filtering by name and phone number. Filtering by geographical location is called a geo query. Firebase doesn't directly support geo queries, so what you can do is to convert your locations into a [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and filter based on those.

Comment: @Hazaaa thank you so much!

Comment: @Abion47 thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as Community Wiki, based in the comments provided.

In this video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&feature=youtu.be), you should be able to have a good glance on how you can query on Firestore, basically with exactly what you are trying to do. Besides that, you have also this clarification in text [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation), for better explanation. In the official documentation, there is also [this repository](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/friendlyeats-web/) with code, on how to achieve this goal.

Regarding the geolocation part, you will need to work with geo queries. Firebase doesn't directly support geo queries, so what you can do is to convert your locations into a [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) an filter with this.